# What's the meaning of 'stopover' here? (movie dialogue, "The Defiant Ones", 1958)

Tags: word-meaning

[Several lines](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/d/defiant-ones-script-transcript-poitier.html) of dialogue from the movie "[The Defiant Ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Defiant_Ones)" (1958):

> - Somebody gotta fix them cars.
> - Let somebody else fix them cars. Me? I wanna drive 'em!
> - You gotta buy 'em first.
> - On a buck-eighty an hour? That's just a **stopover** for a second-hand Chevy. Nah, not for me. I got smart. You're a maker or a taker. Me, I'm a taker.

Now, a [stopover](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stop-over) is "a short interruption in a journey or the place visited during such an interruption", according to Wiktionary. There seems to be no slang meaning.

From the context, he seems to mean "that's just **enough** to buy a second-hand Chevy". Why *stopover* then?

Or is it that he means "That's just **half-way enough** to buy a second-hand Chevy"?

In that case, it was the preposition **for** that beguiled me. Had there been **to** in its place, it would've been clearer to me: "That's just a half-way **to** buying a second-hand Chevy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like he's come up with an alternative to "stopgap".  The choice you make when what you really want is not something you can have at the moment.

Comment: Yes, **stopgap** fits nicely, that also explains the preposition **for**. Thank you, @TRomano!

Comment: I'm having second thoughts. Although a second-hand Chevy would be just a stopgap for him, as it's clearly not his dream car, the antecedent to "that's" seems to be the fact that all he earns is "a buck-eighty an hour". It could be that the desired "destination" is dream car, the remote destination still beyond his reach is "second-hand Chevy", and where he can go on $1.80/hour is some little town between here and "second-hand Chevy".  So the metaphor is "car as destination".

Comment: "that's just a stopover" = "those earnings are only enough to get me halfway to some place that is itself very far from my dream destination."  It's quite elliptical.  I agree with your reading.

Comment: You were concerned about "for". As you know, we normally see *stopover for {travelers: ships, tourists, migrant birds, etc}* or *stopover for {purpose: refueling, food, etc}.* But we do see *for* used with destinations in such locutions as "The ship was bound for Tahiti* or "They were heading for high ground." It's not too much of a stretch to think "for" is used in that destination sense in this elliptical passage.